# Close Accordion element when another element opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Accordion. It's going great, however, when I open a link then open a 2nd link, the original link doesn't close. How do I resolve this?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g8xxh1Lp/

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="singleacord">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active">
                      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">General</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                      <div>
                        <ul class="red_bullets">
                          <li>
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse11">Test 1</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse11">
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Test 1 Textx</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="red_bullets">
                          <li>
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse22">Test 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse22">
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Test 2 Text</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your structures is a little different.  Try something like this:http://www.bootply.com/peFUdnwOpZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give an `id` - `accordion` to your `div` and `class` - `panel - group` which is the parent of `ul.red_bullets` and wrap `red_bullets` within one more `div` with `class` - `panel panel-default`. That's how the grouping or structure should be. Check out the below updated snippet

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="singleacord">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active">
                      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">General</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion"> <!--This here-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default"><!--and this-->
                          <ul class="red_bullets">
                            <li>
                              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse11">Test 1</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse11">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Test 1 Textx</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <ul class="red_bullets">
                            <li>
                              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse22">Test 2</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse22">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                              <p>Test 2 Text</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bootstrap accordion like this.

```html
<! doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```